# Expand sunburst echarts on each click

Tags: javascript, echarts

I have a sunburst graph in echarts which looks something like this:

I wanted to modify this so there is one single button and as you click on it, it displays all the nodes one by one, so first the year then the months, then days and so on.

Here is the code for my graph:

```
var data = [

    {
      "name": 2017,
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Jun",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": 20,
              "children": [
                {
                  "name": "13:55",
                  "children": [
                    {
                      "name": "1.0.0",
                      "children": [
                        {
                          "name": "BC",
                          "itemStyle": {
                            "color": "#ad213e"
                          },
                          "collapsed": true,
                          "children": [
                            {
                              "name": " path rem. w/o depr",
                              "original": "api-path-rem.-w/o-deprecation",
                              "value": 5,
                              "itemStyle": {
                                "color": "#ad213e"
                              },
                              "collapsed": true,
                              "breaking": true
                            }
                          ],
                          "value": 5
                        },
                        {
                          "name": "NBC",
                          "itemStyle": {
                            "color": "#7FB3D5"
                          },
                          "children": [
                            {
                              "name": " title modified",
                              "original": "api title modified",
                              "value": 1,
                              "itemStyle": {
                                "color": "#7FB3D5"
                              },
                              "breaking": false
                            },
                            {
                              "name": " description modified",
                              "original": "api description modified",
                              "value": 1,
                              "itemStyle": {
                                "color": "#7FB3D5"
                              },
                              "breaking": false
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "path added",
                              "original": "path added",
                              "value": 3,
                              "itemStyle": {
                                "color": "#7FB3D5"
                              },
                              "breaking": false
                            }
                          ],
                          "value": 5
                        }
                      ],
                      "itemStyle": {},
                      "value": 10
                    }
                  ],
                  "day": 20,
                  "month": "Jun",
                  "year": 2017,
                  "itemStyle": {
                    "color": ""
                  }
                }
              ],
              "month": "Jun",
              "year": 2017,
              "itemStyle": {
                "color": ""
              }
            },
            {
              "name": 26,
              "children": [
                {
                  "name": "12:11",
                  "children": [
                    {
                      "name": "1.0.0",
                      "children": [
                        {
                          "name": "BC",
                          "itemStyle": {
                            "color": "#ad213e"
                          },
                          "collapsed": true,
                          "children": [
                            {
                              "name": " path rem. w/o depr",
                              "original": "api-path-rem.-w/o-deprecation",
                              "value": 5,
                              "itemStyle": {
                                "color": "#ad213e"
                              },
                              "collapsed": true,
                              "breaking": true
                            }
                          ],
                          "value": 5
                        },
                        {
                          "name": "NBC",
                          "itemStyle": {
                            "color": "#7FB3D5"
                          },
                          "children": [
                            {
                              "name": " title modified",
                              "original": "api title modified",
                              "value": 1,
                              "itemStyle": {
                                "color": "#7FB3D5"
                              },
                              "breaking": false
                            },
                            {
                              "name": " description modified",
                              "original": "api description modified",
                              "value": 1,
                              "itemStyle": {
                                "color": "#7FB3D5"
                              },
                              "breaking": false
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "path added",
                              "original": "path added",
                              "value": 5,
                              "itemStyle": {
                                "color": "#7FB3D5"
                              },
                              "breaking": false
                            }
                          ],
                          "value": 7
                        }
                      ],
                      "itemStyle": {
                        "color": "#fff"
                      },
                      "value": 12
                    }
                  ],
                  "day": 26,
                  "month": "Jun",
                  "year": 2017,
                  "itemStyle": {
                    "color": ""
                  }
                }
              ],
              "month": "Jun",
              "year": 2017,
              "itemStyle": {
                "color": ""
              }
            },
            {
              "name": 28,
              "children": [
                {
                  "name": "9:28",
                  "children": [
                    {
                      "name": "1.0.0",
                      "children": [
                        {
                          "name": "NBC",
                          "itemStyle": {
                            "color": "#7FB3D5"
                          },
                          "children": [
                            {
                              "name": "summ. of method POST modified",
                              "original": "summ. of method POST modified",
                              "value": 1,
                              "itemStyle": {
                                "color": "#7FB3D5"
                              },
                              "breaking": false
                            }
                          ],
                          "value": 1
                        }
                      ],
                      "itemStyle": {
                        "color": "#fff"
                      },
                      "value": 1
                    }
                  ],
                  "day": 28,
                  "month": "Jun",
                  "year": 2017,
                  "itemStyle": {
                    "color": ""
                  }
                },
                {
                  "name": "10:30",
                  "children": [
                    {
                      "name": "1.0.0",
                      "children": [
                        {
                          "name": "BC",
                          "itemStyle": {
                            "color": "#ad213e"
                          },
                          "collapsed": true,
                          "children": [
                            {
                              "name": "new required req param",
                              "original": "new-required-request-parameter",
                              "value": 6,
                              "itemStyle": {
                                "color": "#ad213e"
                              },
                              "collapsed": true,
                              "breaking": true
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "req param rem.",
                              "original": "request-parameter-rem.",
                              "value": 6,
                              "itemStyle": {
                                "color": "#ad213e"
                              },
                              "collapsed": true,
                              "breaking": true
                            }
                          ],
                          "value": 12
                        }
                      ],
                      "itemStyle": {
                        "color": "#fff"
                      },
                      "value": 12
                    }
                  ],
                  "day": 28,
                  "month": "Jun",
                  "year": 2017,
                  "itemStyle": {
                    "color": ""
                  }
                }
              ],
              "month": "Jun",
              "year": 2017,
              "itemStyle": {
                "color": ""
              },
              "value": {
                "$numberDouble": "NaN"
              }
            }
          ],
          "year": 2017,
          "itemStyle": {
            "color": ""
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "Jul",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": 14,
              "children": [
                {
                  "name": "10:57",
                  "children": [
                    {
                      "name": "1.0.0",
                      "children": [
                        {
                          "name": "BC",
                          "itemStyle": {
                            "color": "#ad213e"
                          },
                          "collapsed": true,
                          "children": [
                            {
                              "name": "new required req param",
                              "original": "new-required-request-parameter",
                              "value": 1,
                              "itemStyle": {
                                "color": "#ad213e"
                              },
                              "collapsed": true,
                              "breaking": true
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "req param rem.",
                              "original": "request-parameter-rem.",
                              "value": 4,
                              "itemStyle": {
                                "color": "#ad213e"
                              },
                              "collapsed": true,
                              "breaking": true
                            }
                          ],
                          "value": 5
                        }
                      ],
                      "itemStyle": {
                        "color": "#fff"
                      },
                      "value": 5
                    }
                  ],
                  "day": 14,
                  "month": "Jul",
                  "year": 2017,
                  "itemStyle": {
                    "color": ""
                  }
                }
              ],
              "month": "Jul",
              "year": 2017,
              "itemStyle": {
                "color": ""
              }
            },
            {
              "name": 17,
              "children": [
                {
                  "name": "13:11",
                  "children": [
                    {
                      "name": "1.0.0",
                      "children": [
                        {
                          "name": "BC",
                          "itemStyle": {
                            "color": "#ad213e"
                          },
                          "collapsed": true,
                          "children": [
                            {
                              "name": " path rem. w/o depr",
                              "original": "api-path-rem.-w/o-deprecation",
                              "value": 1,
                              "itemStyle": {
                                "color": "#ad213e"
                              },
                              "collapsed": true,
                              "breaking": true
                            }
                          ],
                          "value": 1
                        },
                        {
                          "name": "NBC",
                          "itemStyle": {
                            "color": "#7FB3D5"
                          },
                          "children": [
                            {
                              "name": "path added",
                              "original": "path added",
                              "value": 1,
                              "itemStyle": {
                                "color": "#7FB3D5"
                              },
                              "breaking": false
                            }
                          ],
                          "value": 1
                        }
                      ],
                      "itemStyle": {
                        "color": "#fff"
                      },
                      "value": 2
                    }
                  ],
                  "day": 17,
                  "month": "Jul",
                  "year": 2017,
                  "itemStyle": {
                    "color": ""
                  }
                },
                {
                  "name": "16:22",
                  "children": [
                    {
                      "name": "1.0.0",
                      "children": [],
                      "itemStyle": {
                        "color": "#fff"
                      }
                    }
                  ],
                  "day": 17,
                  "month": "Jul",
                  "year": 2017,
                  "itemStyle": {
                    "color": ""
                  }
                }
              ],
              "month": "Jul",
              "year": 2017,
              "itemStyle": {
                "color": ""
              },
              "value": {
                "$numberDouble": "NaN"
              }
            },
            {
              "name": 27,
              "children": [
                {
                  "name": "12:29",
                  "children": [
                    {
                      "name": "1.0.0",
                      "children": [
                        {
                          "name": "BC",
                          "itemStyle": {
                            "color": "#ad213e"
                          },
                          "collapsed": true,
                          "children": [
                            {
                              "name": " path rem. w/o depr",
                              "original": "api-path-rem.-w/o-deprecation",
                              "value": 5,
                              "itemStyle": {
                                "color": "#ad213e"
                              },
                              "collapsed": true,
                              "breaking": true
                            }
                          ],
                          "value": 5
                        },
                        {
                          "name": "NBC",
                          "itemStyle": {
                            "color": "#7FB3D5"
                          },
                          "children": [
                            {
                              "name": "path added",
                              "original": "path added",
                              "value": 5,
                              "itemStyle": {
                                "color": "#7FB3D5"
                              },
                              "breaking": false
                            }
                          ],
                          "value": 5
                        }
                      ],
                      "itemStyle": {
                        "color": "#fff"
                      },
                      "value": 10
                    }
                  ],
                  "day": 27,
                  "month": "Jul",
                  "year": 2017,
                  "itemStyle": {
                    "color": ""
                  }
                }
              ],
              "month": "Jul",
              "year": 2017,
              "itemStyle": {
                "color": ""
              }
            }
          ],
          "year": 2017,
          "itemStyle": {
            "color": ""
          }
        },
      ],
      "itemStyle": {
        "color": ""
      }
    },
    {
      "name": 2018,
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "May",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": 15,
              "children": [
                {
                  "name": "16:32",
                  "children": [
                    {
                      "name": "1.0.0",
                      "children": [
                        {
                          "name": "NBC",
                          "itemStyle": {
                            "color": "#7FB3D5"
                          },
                          "children": [
                            {
                              "name": " title modified",
                              "original": "api title modified",
                              "value": 1,
                              "itemStyle": {
                                "color": "#7FB3D5"
                              },
                              "breaking": false
                            },
                            {
                              "name": " description modified",
                              "original": "api description modified",
                              "value": 1,
                              "itemStyle": {
                                "color": "#7FB3D5"
                              },
                              "breaking": false
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "path added",
                              "original": "path added",
                              "value": 1,
                              "itemStyle": {
                                "color": "#7FB3D5"
                              },
                              "breaking": false
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "summ. of method GET modified",
                              "original": "summ. of method GET modified",
                              "value": 3,
                              "itemStyle": {
                                "color": "#7FB3D5"
                              },
                              "breaking": false
                            }
                          ],
                          "value": 6
                        }
                      ],
                      "itemStyle": {
                        "color": "#fff"
                      },
                      "value": 6
                    }
                  ],
                  "day": 15,
                  "month": "May",
                  "year": 2018,
                  "itemStyle": {
                    "color": ""
                  }
                }
              ],
              "month": "May",
              "year": 2018,
              "itemStyle": {
                "color": ""
              }
            },
            {
              "name": 21,
              "children": [
                {
                  "name": "10:39",
                  "children": [
                    {
                      "name": "1.0.0",
                      "children": [
                        {
                          "name": "NBC",
                          "itemStyle": {
                            "color": "#7FB3D5"
                          },
                          "children": [
                            {
                              "name": " title modified",
                              "original": "api title modified",
                              "value": 1,
                              "itemStyle": {
                                "color": "#7FB3D5"
                              },
                              "breaking": false
                            }
                          ],
                          "value": 1
                        }
                      ],
                      "itemStyle": {
                        "color": "#fff"
                      },
                      "value": 1
                    }
                  ],
                  "day": 21,
                  "month": "May",
                  "year": 2018,
                  "itemStyle": {
                    "color": ""
                  }
                }
              ],
              "month": "May",
              "year": 2018,
              "itemStyle": {
                "color": ""
              }
            },
          ],
          "year": 2018,
          "itemStyle": {
            "color": ""
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "Aug",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": 1,
              "children": [
                {
                  "name": "8:20",
                  "children": [
                    {
                      "name": "1.0.0",
                      "children": [
                        {
                          "name": "BC",
                          "itemStyle": {
                            "color": "#ad213e"
                          },
                          "collapsed": true,
                          "children": [
                            {
                              "name": "req param rem.",
                              "original": "request-parameter-rem.",
                              "value": 8,
                              "itemStyle": {
                                "color": "#ad213e"
                              },
                              "collapsed": true,
                              "breaking": true
                            }
                          ],
                          "value": 8
                        }
                      ],
                      "itemStyle": {
                        "color": "#fff"
                      },
                      "value": 8
                    }
                  ],
                  "day": 1,
                  "month": "Aug",
                  "year": 2018,
                  "itemStyle": {
                    "color": ""
                  }
                }
              ],
              "month": "Aug",
              "year": 2018,
              "itemStyle": {
                "color": ""
              }
            }
          ],
          "year": 2018,
          "itemStyle": {
            "color": ""
          }
        }
      ],
      "itemStyle": {
        "color": ""
      }
    },
    {
      "name": 2021,
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Feb",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": 11,
              "children": [
                {
                  "name": "14:2:9",
                  "children": [
                    {
                      "name": "1.0.0",
                      "children": [],
                      "itemStyle": {
                        "color": "#fff"
                      }
                    }
                  ],
                  "day": 11,
                  "month": "Feb",
                  "year": 2021,
                  "itemStyle": {
                    "color": "#a8a8a8"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "name": "14:8:14",
                  "children": [
                    {
                      "name": "1.0.0",
                      "children": [],
                      "itemStyle": {
                        "color": "#fff"
                      }
                    }
                  ],
                  "day": 11,
                  "month": "Feb",
                  "year": 2021,
                  "itemStyle": {
                    "color": "#a8a8a8"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "name": "15:59:56",
                  "children": [
                    {
                      "name": "1.0.0",
                      "children": [],
                      "itemStyle": {
                        "color": "#fff"
                      }
                    }
                  ],
                  "day": 11,
                  "month": "Feb",
                  "year": 2021,
                  "itemStyle": {
                    "color": "#a8a8a8"
                  }
                }
              ],
              "month": "Feb",
              "year": 2021,
              "itemStyle": {
                "color": "#a8a8a8"
              },
              "value": {
                "$numberDouble": "NaN"
              }
            }
          ],
          "year": 2021,
          "itemStyle": {
            "color": "#a8a8a8"
          }
        }
      ],
      "itemStyle": {
        "color": "#a8a8a8"
      }
    }
];
option = {
  title: {
    textStyle: {
      fontSize: 24,
      fontFamily: 'Times New Roman',
      align: 'center'
    },
    subtextStyle: {
      align: 'center',
      fontSize: 18,
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      fontFamily: 'Times New Roman',
    }
  },
  series: {
    type: 'sunburst',
    data: data,
    width:2000,
    height:1600,
    radius: [0, '60%'],
    sort: undefined,
    label: {
      formatter: '{b}',
      position: 'inside',
      distance: 0,
      rotate: 'radial'
    },
    levels: [
      {},
      {
        itemStyle: {
          colorAlpha: 0
        }
      },
      {
        itemStyle: {
          colorAlpha: 0
        }
      },
      {
        itemStyle: {
          colorAlpha: 0
        }
      },
      {
        itemStyle: {
          colorAlpha: 0
        }
      },
      {
        itemStyle: {
          colorAlpha: 0
        }
      },
      {
        itemStyle: {
          colorAlpha: 0
        }
      },
      {
        label: {
          formatter: '{b}',
          position: 'outside',
          distance: 2, // Adjust the distance to increase the gap between the chart and the labels
          depth: 0, // Adjust this value to set the depth level for labels
          rotate: 'radial' // Rotate the labels around the sunburst chart
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Is there a way this could be achieved, I am not very good with javascript so any suggestions or ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Echarts

**ECharts currently does not provide a straightforward way to set the maximum number of displayed levels.** This could actually be addressed... I initially wrote a script to modify your array by removing unnecessary levels, but I realized that I was not heading in the right direction because - unfortunately - you did not provide the `itemStyle.color` and `value` values for each level, which makes it impossible for ECharts to interpret the array correctly even if I remove the last level (`children`) where this was given.

If you were to provide `itemStyle.color` and `value` values for each element, you could simply override the value of `option.series.data` with the press of a button and re-render the chart.

**Important! Every element needs to have a `value` and `itemStyle.color` assigned to it, otherwise echarts will not be able to display the specific level where this is not fulfilled.**

```js
const data = [...]
const option = {...}

let level = 0

const getDataToLevel = (data, currLevel) => {
  // need a procedure that returns the children up to a certain level, and then stops
  
  if (level <= 0) {
    return data.map(obj => ({
      ...obj,
      children: []
    }));
  }

  let result = [];

  for (let obj of data) {
    let newObj = {
      ...obj,
      children: Array.isArray(obj.children) ? getDataToLevel(obj.children, level - 1) : []
    };

    result.push(newObj);
  }

  return result;
}

const updateChart = (currChart, currOption, currData, currLevel) => {
  currOption.series.data = getDataToLevel(currData, currLevel)
  currChart.setOption(currOption)
}
```

```html
<button id="collapseButton">-</button>
<button id="expandButton">+</button>
```

```js
/**
 ** Expand Button
 */
const expandButton = document.getElementById('expandButton')
expandButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // Need higher level
  level++
  // After... need update chart
  updateChart(chart, option, data, level)
})

/**
 ** Collapse Button
 */
const collapseButton = document.getElementById('collapseButton')
collapseButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // Need smaller level
  if (level > 0) level--
  // After... need update chart
  updateChart(chart, option, data, level)
})
```

### Alternative Solution

However, we can customize the format of each level separately, which you have already started implementing in the `option.series.levels` property. I thought about this further.

I created two buttons: expand and collapse. I assigned a click event to them. Essentially, they either increase or decrease the value of the global level variable by 1, and then call the chart update function.

```html
<button id="collapseButton">-</button>
<button id="expandButton">+</button>
```

```js
/**
 ** Current Level
 */
let level = 0

/**
 ** Expand Button
 */
const expandButton = document.getElementById('expandButton')
expandButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // Need higher level
  level++
  // After... need update chart
  updateChart(chart, option, level)
})

/**
 ** Collapse Button
 */
const collapseButton = document.getElementById('collapseButton')
collapseButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // Need smaller level
  if (level > 0) level--
  // After... need update chart
  updateChart(chart, option, level)
})
```

In the chart update function, I instructed the program to make every level with an index greater than the current global level invisible. That means I specified that the element should be transparent, and its label should not be displayed.

```js
/**
 ** Update Chart
 * @param {HTMLElement} currChart (chart)
 * @param {object} currOption (option)
 * @param {number} currLevel (level)
 */
const updateChart = (currChart, currOption, currLevel) => {
  // Check pre-defined levels
  currOption.series.levels.map((lvl, index) => {
    // If index higher than current level --> need hide it
    if (index > currLevel) {
      lvl.label = {...(lvl.label ?? {}), ...{ show: false }} // text
      lvl.itemStyle = {...(lvl.itemStyle ?? {}), ...{ opacity: 0 }} // item color
    }
    // If index smaller or equal than current level --> need show it
    else {
      lvl.label = {...(lvl.label ?? {}), ...{ show: true }} // text
      lvl.itemStyle = {...(lvl.itemStyle ?? {}), ...{ opacity: 1 }} / item color
    }
    
    return lvl
  })
  currChart.setOption(currOption)
}
```

### Example

(Unfortunately, I deleted the last level from data as it became too long to provide an example that Stack Overflow no longer allowed me to share, but it doesn't lose its value.)

```js
/**
 ** Initialize
 */
const chartDom = document.getElementById('chart')
const chart = echarts.init(chartDom)

/**
 ** Data
 */
const data = [
  {
    name: 2017,
    children: [
      {
        name: 'Jun',
        children: [
          {
            name: 20,
            children: [
              {
                name: '13:55',
                children: [
                  {
                    name: '1.0.0',
                    children: [
                      {
                        name: 'BC',
                        itemStyle: {
                          color: '#ad213e',
                        },
                        collapsed: true,
                        children: [],
                        value: 5,
                      },
                      {
                        name: 'NBC',
                        itemStyle: {
                          color: '#7FB3D5',
                        },
                        children: [],
                        value: 5,
                      },
                    ],
                    itemStyle: {},
                    value: 10,
                  },
                ],
                day: 20,
                month: 'Jun',
                year: 2017,
                itemStyle: {
                  color: '',
                },
              },
            ],
            month: 'Jun',
            year: 2017,
            itemStyle: {
              color: '',
            },
          },
          {
            name: 26,
            children: [
              {
                name: '12:11',
                children: [
                  {
                    name: '1.0.0',
                    children: [
                      {
                        name: 'BC',
                        itemStyle: {
                          color: '#ad213e',
                        },
                        collapsed: true,
                        children: [],
                        value: 5,
                      },
                      {
                        name: 'NBC',
                        itemStyle: {
                          color: '#7FB3D5',
                        },
                        children: [],
                        value: 7,
                      },
                    ],
                    itemStyle: {
                      color: '#fff',
                    },
                    value: 12,
                  },
                ],
                day: 26,
                month: 'Jun',
                year: 2017,
                itemStyle: {
                  color: '',
                },
              },
            ],
            month: 'Jun',
            year: 2017,
            itemStyle: {
              color: '',
            },
          },
          {
            name: 28,
            children: [
              {
                name: '9:28',
                children: [
                  {
                    name: '1.0.0',
                    children: [
                      {
                        name: 'NBC',
                        itemStyle: {
                          color: '#7FB3D5',
                        },
                        children: [],
                        value: 1,
                      },
                    ],
                    itemStyle: {
                      color: '#fff',
                    },
                    value: 1,
                  },
                ],
                day: 28,
                month: 'Jun',
                year: 2017,
                itemStyle: {
                  color: '',
                },
              },
              {
                name: '10:30',
                children: [
                  {
                    name: '1.0.0',
                    children: [
                      {
                        name: 'BC',
                        itemStyle: {
                          color: '#ad213e',
                        },
                        collapsed: true,
                        children: [],
                        value: 12,
                      },
                    ],
                    itemStyle: {
                      color: '#fff',
                    },
                    value: 12,
                  },
                ],
                day: 28,
                month: 'Jun',
                year: 2017,
                itemStyle: {
                  color: '',
                },
              },
            ],
            month: 'Jun',
            year: 2017,
            itemStyle: {
              color: '',
            },
            value: {
              $numberDouble: 'NaN',
            },
          },
        ],
        year: 2017,
        itemStyle: {
          color: '',
        },
      },
      {
        name: 'Jul',
        children: [
          {
            name: 14,
            children: [
              {
                name: '10:57',
                children: [
                  {
                    name: '1.0.0',
                    children: [
                      {
                        name: 'BC',
                        itemStyle: {
                          color: '#ad213e',
                        },
                        collapsed: true,
                        children: [],
                        value: 5,
                      },
                    ],
                    itemStyle: {
                      color: '#fff',
                    },
                    value: 5,
                  },
                ],
                day: 14,
                month: 'Jul',
                year: 2017,
                itemStyle: {
                  color: '',
                },
              },
            ],
            month: 'Jul',
            year: 2017,
            itemStyle: {
              color: '',
            },
          },
          {
            name: 17,
            children: [
              {
                name: '13:11',
                children: [
                  {
                    name: '1.0.0',
                    children: [
                      {
                        name: 'BC',
                        itemStyle: {
                          color: '#ad213e',
                        },
                        collapsed: true,
                        children: [],
                        value: 1,
                      },
                      {
                        name: 'NBC',
                        itemStyle: {
                          color: '#7FB3D5',
                        },
                        children: [
                          {
                            name: 'path added',
                            original: 'path added',
                            value: 1,
                            itemStyle: {
                              color: '#7FB3D5',
                            },
                            breaking: false,
                          },
                        ],
                        value: 1,
                      },
                    ],
                    itemStyle: {
                      color: '#fff',
                    },
                    value: 2,
                  },
                ],
                day: 17,
                month: 'Jul',
                year: 2017,
                itemStyle: {
                  color: '',
                },
              },
              {
                name: '16:22',
                children: [
                  {
                    name: '1.0.0',
                    children: [],
                    itemStyle: {
                      color: '#fff',
                    },
                  },
                ],
                day: 17,
                month: 'Jul',
                year: 2017,
                itemStyle: {
                  color: '',
                },
              },
            ],
            month: 'Jul',
            year: 2017,
            itemStyle: {
              color: '',
            },
            value: {
              $numberDouble: 'NaN',
            },
          },
          {
            name: 27,
            children: [
              {
                name: '12:29',
                children: [
                  {
                    name: '1.0.0',
                    children: [
                      {
                        name: 'BC',
                        itemStyle: {
                          color: '#ad213e',
                        },
                        collapsed: true,
                        children: [],
                        value: 5,
                      },
                      {
                        name: 'NBC',
                        itemStyle: {
                          color: '#7FB3D5',
                        },
                        children: [],
                        value: 5,
                      },
                    ],
                    itemStyle: {
                      color: '#fff',
                    },
                    value: 10,
                  },
                ],
                day: 27,
                month: 'Jul',
                year: 2017,
                itemStyle: {
                  color: '',
                },
              },
            ],
            month: 'Jul',
            year: 2017,
            itemStyle: {
              color: '',
            },
          },
        ],
        year: 2017,
        itemStyle: {
          color: '',
        },
      },
    ],
    itemStyle: {
      color: '',
    },
  },
  {
    name: 2018,
    children: [
      {
        name: 'May',
        children: [
          {
            name: 15,
            children: [
              {
                name: '16:32',
                children: [
                  {
                    name: '1.0.0',
                    children: [
                      {
                        name: 'NBC',
                        itemStyle: {
                          color: '#7FB3D5',
                        },
                        children: [],
                        value: 6,
                      },
                    ],
                    itemStyle: {
                      color: '#fff',
                    },
                    value: 6,
                  },
                ],
                day: 15,
                month: 'May',
                year: 2018,
                itemStyle: {
                  color: '',
                },
              },
            ],
            month: 'May',
            year: 2018,
            itemStyle: {
              color: '',
            },
          },
          {
            name: 21,
            children: [
              {
                name: '10:39',
                children: [
                  {
                    name: '1.0.0',
                    children: [
                      {
                        name: 'NBC',
                        itemStyle: {
                          color: '#7FB3D5',
                        },
                        children: [],
                        value: 1,
                      },
                    ],
                    itemStyle: {
                      color: '#fff',
                    },
                    value: 1,
                  },
                ],
                day: 21,
                month: 'May',
                year: 2018,
                itemStyle: {
                  color: '',
                },
              },
            ],
            month: 'May',
            year: 2018,
            itemStyle: {
              color: '',
            },
          },
        ],
        year: 2018,
        itemStyle: {
          color: '',
        },
      },
      {
        name: 'Aug',
        children: [
          {
            name: 1,
            children: [
              {
                name: '8:20',
                children: [
                  {
                    name: '1.0.0',
                    children: [
                      {
                        name: 'BC',
                        itemStyle: {
                          color: '#ad213e',
                        },
                        collapsed: true,
                        children: [],
                        value: 8,
                      },
                    ],
                    itemStyle: {
                      color: '#fff',
                    },
                    value: 8,
                  },
                ],
                day: 1,
                month: 'Aug',
                year: 2018,
                itemStyle: {
                  color: '',
                },
              },
            ],
            month: 'Aug',
            year: 2018,
            itemStyle: {
              color: '',
            },
          },
        ],
        year: 2018,
        itemStyle: {
          color: '',
        },
      },
    ],
    itemStyle: {
      color: '',
    },
  },
  {
    name: 2021,
    children: [
      {
        name: 'Feb',
        children: [
          {
            name: 11,
            children: [
              {
                name: '14:2:9',
                children: [
                  {
                    name: '1.0.0',
                    children: [],
                    itemStyle: {
                      color: '#fff',
                    },
                  },
                ],
                day: 11,
                month: 'Feb',
                year: 2021,
                itemStyle: {
                  color: '#a8a8a8',
                },
              },
              {
                name: '14:8:14',
                children: [
                  {
                    name: '1.0.0',
                    children: [],
                    itemStyle: {
                      color: '#fff',
                    },
                  },
                ],
                day: 11,
                month: 'Feb',
                year: 2021,
                itemStyle: {
                  color: '#a8a8a8',
                },
              },
              {
                name: '15:59:56',
                children: [
                  {
                    name: '1.0.0',
                    children: [],
                    itemStyle: {
                      color: '#fff',
                    },
                  },
                ],
                day: 11,
                month: 'Feb',
                year: 2021,
                itemStyle: {
                  color: '#a8a8a8',
                },
              },
            ],
            month: 'Feb',
            year: 2021,
            itemStyle: {
              color: '#a8a8a8',
            },
            value: {
              $numberDouble: 'NaN',
            },
          },
        ],
        year: 2021,
        itemStyle: {
          color: '#a8a8a8',
        },
      },
    ],
    itemStyle: {
      color: '#a8a8a8',
    },
  },
]

/**
 ** Option
 */
const option = {
  title: {
    textStyle: {
      fontSize: 24,
      fontFamily: 'Times New Roman',
      align: 'center',
    },
    subtextStyle: {
      align: 'center',
      fontSize: 18,
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      fontFamily: 'Times New Roman',
    },
  },
  series: {
    type: 'sunburst',
    data: data,
    width: 300,
    height: 300,
    radius: [0, '100%'], // [0, '60%'],
    sort: undefined,
    label: {
      formatter: '{b}',
      position: 'inside',
      distance: 0,
      rotate: 'radial',
    },
    levels: [
      {},
      {
        itemStyle: {
          colorAlpha: 0,
        },
      },
      {
        itemStyle: {
          colorAlpha: 0,
        },
      },
      {
        itemStyle: {
          colorAlpha: 0,
        },
      },
      {
        itemStyle: {
          colorAlpha: 0,
        },
      },
      {
        itemStyle: {
          colorAlpha: 0,
        },
      },
      {
        itemStyle: {
          colorAlpha: 0,
        },
      },
      {
        label: {
          formatter: '{b}',
          position: 'outside',
          distance: 2, // Adjust the distance to increase the gap between the chart and the labels
          depth: 0, // Adjust this value to set the depth level for labels
          rotate: 'radial', // Rotate the labels around the sunburst chart
        },
      },
    ],
  },
}

/* *********************************************************** */

/**
 ** Current Level
 */
let level = 0

/**
 ** Expand Button
 */
const expandButton = document.getElementById('expandButton')
expandButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  level++
  updateChart(chart, option, level)
})

/**
 ** Collapse Button
 */
const collapseButton = document.getElementById('collapseButton')
collapseButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (level > 0) level--
  updateChart(chart, option, level)
})

/* *********************************************************** */

/**
 ** Update Chart
 * @param {HTMLElement} currChart (chart)
 * @param {object} currOption (option)
 * @param {number} currLevel (level)
 */
const updateChart = (currChart, currOption, currLevel) => {
  currOption.series.levels.map((lvl, index) => {
    if (index > currLevel) {
      lvl.label = {...(lvl.label ?? {}), ...{ show: false }}
      lvl.itemStyle = {...(lvl.itemStyle ?? {}), ...{ opacity: 0 }}
    }
    else {
      lvl.label = {...(lvl.label ?? {}), ...{ show: true }}
      lvl.itemStyle = {...(lvl.itemStyle ?? {}), ...{ opacity: 1 }}
    }
    
    return lvl
  })
  currChart.setOption(currOption)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/5.4.2/echarts.min.js" integrity="sha512-VdqgeoWrVJcsDXFlQEKqE5MyhaIgB9yXUVaiUa8DR2J4Lr1uWcFm+ZH/YnzV5WqgKf4GPyHQ64vVLgzqGIchyw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<button id="collapseButton">-</button>
<button id="expandButton">+</button>
<div id="chart" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;"></div>
```

Comment: This answer is brilliant, thank you so much for the detailed explanation, it helps me in learning alot, I tried it out in Codepen and it works amazing, however there is one thing I wanted to ask if due to the customization, any affect falls on embedding the graph? i was trying to put it in my presentation however i cannot see it. They have blocked me giving the bounty for 21 hours for I don't know what reason, I will award it once the timer is gone

Comment: I'm glad I could help! I have modified the `getDataToLevel()` function. If you still want to try out the initial version... although it might be a lot of work to calculate all the values, the end result could be impressive.

Comment: In the "alternative solution", I modified the changes to `levels[].label`. Show and `levels[].itemStyle.opacity` so that they would work even if they don't exist beforehand (see: `?? {}`). Additionally, only those specific settings were modified, and no other changes were made (see: object merging).

Comment: If you are implementing ECharts into a presentation, you will need the JavaScript code I provided. Unfortunately, I don't know the specific way you are implementing it, so I can't assist further. However, it is certain that JavaScript is required for the implementation.